# My custom WCF Service can only be access using http://<servername>:<port>/_vti_bin/myservice.svc

Tags: wcf

I've used the ["Walkthrough: Creating and Implementing a Custom WCF Service in SharePoint Foundation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521584.aspx) from MSDN to create my cusom WCF Service and deploy to my Sharepoint 2010 server.

The wsp is globally deployed and when I access the service in the browser using the url: http://myserver/_vti_bin/Revert.svc/MEX everything seems ok. The problem is when I need to access the service on another webapplication on the server: http://intranet.mydomain.com/_vti_bin/Revert.svc/MEX. This gives me a "HTTP 400 Bad Request" error. This webapplication was created on port 81, so I can access the service by using the url: http://myserver:81/_vti_bin/Revert.svc/MEX.

I've set up AAM and also added the binding for port 80 in the IIS Management Console. I can use the builtin services like "listdata.svc" using the http://intranet.mydomain.com url, but not my custom wcf service. Does anyone know why?

Best Regards
ElinK

Comment: What HTTP method did you request, was it GET or POST. If it a POST, you should check the response from the server. In my experience HTTP 400 was because response from the server was not in expected format (json/xml). But it was in html where the server returned page server error in ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the host name in the binding settings in the IIS Management Console? If not the WCF service can not identify the correct urls.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. The SP site works fine, just a custom wcf service has a problem.

I have found that whatever is defined first in the bindings in IIS works and the second one fails. Not much help to me but may help others.

I still don't have an actual fix