# Access to _vti_bin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, project-server, wcf

I'm trying to deploy a WCF hosted on my SharePoint site but I can't find the address where my web service is deployed.

I have a confirmation message which said that my web service is well deployed but I can't reach it!

So my sharepoint site is: `http://Sharepoint/sites/pwa` (it's a project site)

My web service is called `Service1` and it builds in my namespace: Test.PS2016
I tried a lot of paths but I can't find my web service

It's still doesn't work, now I have a new issue, I saw the site but when I click on it I have an error message

So i have my ASP.NET Web Application which is called: Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension

With its iservice and Service (Very simple one):

Iservice:

```
namespace Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool isAlive();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
namespace Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension
    {

   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   internal class Service : IService
  {
    public bool isAlive()
       {
        return (true);
       }
    }
}
```

its Service.svc:

**<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension.Service"  %>**

and its webservice:

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>*
```

and I have my SharePoint solution with its folder ISAPI=>PSI=>Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension.svc  :

The Version, culture and PublicKey comes from a powershell command from the file: Foo.PS2016.PSIExtension.dll

So I have been stucking on this issue since this morning so if someone has some ideas to help me

Comment: Where did you put those wcf files in solution? Was it Under ISAPI? This is another question which directly answer your question if you put it under ISAPI https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/my-custom-wcf-service-can-only-be-access-using-http-servernameport-vti-b?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The **_vti_bin** is the **built-in** SharePoint Web services directory, it's **not** the default directory for the custom deployed web service.

To can deploy your custom WCF to this directory, you should add `ISAPI` as a mapped folder in your SharePoint solution

[image]

In this case, you can find your WCF below **_vti_bin** as the following

```
http://your site collection/_vti_bin/your web service folder/Service1.svc
```

> **Note:** if you have added the web service under layout folder, so it's path should be this
>   `https://Sharepoint/Sites/pwa/_layouts/15/service folder/service1.svc`

Alos please check this good reference to be able to [Create a Custom WCF REST Service Hosted in SharePoint and Deployed in a WSP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

Comment: Thank for your answer
It's weird but my IIS is empty, I don't see any of my Webservice

Comment: How you have deployed your web service, what I know there is publishing profile, to specify the publishing path, please check it's entries!

Comment: I deployed my solution with visual Studio
I build a new sharepointempty project and I added a WCF library

Comment: Please check the updated answer , hope it help :)

Comment: Ok, so I have to put my webservice in the same folder than my sharepoint files, because I followed a guide where they put the webservice in a wcf solution

Comment: **Yes**,just follow the guide

(If the above answer helped you please don't forget to set it as answer, also please don't hesitate to ask if you have further clarification)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I follow your guide but now I have a new error message,  have you any idea?